# Refer dataflow definition from Storage link service in azure python sdk for ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-python-sdk

I am using azure pythOn SDK for ADF, I am looking to create a dataflow dynamically.

I have data flow definitions in json format available on linked storage account.
Is there a way, I can refer definition from storage account and create a dataflow?
like below

```
adf_client.data_flows.create_or_update(location = 'path_to_dataflow_json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No, you cannot refer to the path of the JSON file directly. The definition has to be given in order for you to create or update the dataflow.
- When I install the required packages and use pythons `help` on the `adf_client.data_flows.create_or_update`, you can see what arguments.

```
credentials = ClientSecretCredential(client_id='<client_id', client_secret='<client_secret', tenant_id='<tenant_id>')

adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
help(adf_client.data_flows.create_or_update)
```

[image]

- As you can see in the above image, the dataflow definition requires `azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.DataFlowResource` but there is no parameter that accepts path to the definition file.